# How do I get Solr to return spell check suggestions with diacritics?

Tags: solr

I have in my Solr:

```
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_pl</str>

    <!-- Multiple "Spell Checkers" can be declared and used by this
         component
      -->

    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

and schema:

```
  <fieldType name="text_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_pl.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Now i make query:

```
spell?spellcheck.q=rekawiczki&spellcheck.count=10
```

i dont get any suggestions as Solr thinks its correctly spelled.

And he is right because i removed diacritics with ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.

In my native language (Polish) "rekawiczki" should be "r**ę**kawiczki".
So Solr when i enter "rekawiczki" Solr spellcheck should suggest "rękawiczki".

Does anyone knows how to achieve this in Solr?

**EDIT:**

I have changed **text_pl** definition to:

```
<fieldType name="text_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_pl.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_pl.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Know it corrects me when i write query like:

```
spell?spellcheck.q=rkawiczki&spellcheck.count=10
```

Then it suggests "rękawiczki", but again when i write "rekawiczki" it doesnt sugest anything.